# JHipster custom configuraiton support

Tags: jhipster

I just discovered JHispert looking for a stater for Spring Data + AngularJS Project. I must say I'm impressed. But I want to ask some questions about configuration:

- Is it possible to use mssql & oracle databases?? Liquibase supports them but because their drivers are not available & they're not opensource, it's an issue for DB generation ?? Or can I add manually??
- How easy to modify the screens & app structure?? Instead of seeing all entities under "Entities", I'd have different menus with different screens etc. So only will see, some will add (with custom user rights etc.)... So can I do this without too much pain? how does it work ? I suppose I need to generate some code on AngularJS side and on Spring side, which is quite normal but I just want to know how much work does it require ?

Thanks..

Gokhan

Answer (score 1):

Too many questions for me, so I'm just answering the first one:

- we don't support Oracle & MS Server because they are non-free (we need to have access to the drivers, and we would need to buy the software for our tests)
- they should be very easy to use, as we use Liquibase & JPA which both support Oracle and MS Server

If any body has the time and resources to test those, I would be very happy to add a documentation page about it.

Comment: Thank for your response.First of all, you can download & use free version of both DB, Oracle Express Edition & SQL Server Express. Plus their JDBC driver can be downloaded & used, they're not in maven unfortunately, but users can download drivers manually. I can help to test & docement these ddatabases, please show me where to start..